# jQueryのOneBook3dを使ってページをめくりたいです

Tags: html, jquery, css

HTML、css、jQueryの初心者です。
会社からの指示でホームページを作成することになりました。
作成時間は業務時間外で休日を使うしかない状況です。
デザインはできたのですが、プログラムで大変苦戦しています。
メモの画像をjQueryの機能でページがめくれるようにしたいです。
以下の状況なのですが何も表示されません…
どうぞ宜しくお願いいたします。

■jsフォルダに入っているファイル
jquery.mousewheel.min.js
jquery.onebook3d-2.33.js
jquery-1.11.0.min.js

■CSSフォルダに入っているファイル
jquery-OneBook3d.css

内容

```
html,body{width:100%;margin:1px;padding:0px;background:#cccccc;color:#000000;min-width:800px;}
body * { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);}
.links a:link,.links a:visited{color:black;text-decoration:none;font:15px sans-serif;}
.links a:hover{color:black;text-decoration:underline;}
.headtitle p{text-align:center;margin:0px;padding:20px;font:16px; sans-serif;line-height:140%;}
.headtitle2 p{text-align:center;margin:0px;padding:20px;font:16px; sans-serif;line-height:140%;}
/address{margin:0px auto 50px auto;padding:0px;width:800px;text-align:center;}
/address, .address a{font:13px arial, sans-serif;color:black;}
```

■index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
<meta name="description" content="ページをめくる"> 
<title>ページをめくる</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/jquery-OneBook3d.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/jquery.onebook3d-2.33.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
<script> 
    function ($) {
    var imgArray = [
        ['./img/img_001.jpg', 'title1'],
        ['./img/img_002.jpg', 'title2'],
        ['./img/img_003.jpg', 'title3'],
        ['./img/img_004.jpg', 'title4'],
        ['./img/img_005.jpg', 'title5'],
        ['./img/img_006.jpg', 'title6'],
        ['./img/img_007.jpg', 'title7'],
        ['./img/img_008.jpg', 'title8'],
        ['./img/img_009.jpg', 'title9'],
        ['./img/img_0010.jpg', 'title10'],
        ['./img/img_0011.jpg', 'title11']
    ];

    $('#onebook3dSample').onebook(imgArray, {
        startPage: 1,
        flip: 'soft',
        skin: 'dark',
        bgDark: '#222222 url(./img/desktop.jpg)',
        pageColor: '#FFFFFF',
        slope: 0,
        border: 25,
        language: 'en',
        cesh: true
    });
};
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 以下の状況なのですが何も表示されません…

以下の3点に誤りがあるのではと思います。

- three.min.jsの読み込みが抜けている。

  `<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/three.min.js"></script>`
- onebookを表示する要素(`<div id="onebook3dSample"/>`)が抜けている。

  `<div id="onebook3dSample"></div>`
- jqueryの初期処理の呼出方法が誤っている。

  `$(function () { //..略... });`

修正版は以下になると思います。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="ページをめくる">
    <title>ページをめくる</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/jquery-OneBook3d.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/jquery.onebook3d-2.33.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="onebook3dSample"></div>

    <script>
     $(function () {
       var imgArray = [
         ['./img/img_001.jpg', 'title1'],
         ['./img/img_002.jpg', 'title2'],
         ['./img/img_003.jpg', 'title3'],
         ['./img/img_004.jpg', 'title4'],
         ['./img/img_005.jpg', 'title5'],
         ['./img/img_006.jpg', 'title6'],
         ['./img/img_007.jpg', 'title7'],
         ['./img/img_008.jpg', 'title8'],
         ['./img/img_009.jpg', 'title9'],
         ['./img/img_0010.jpg', 'title10'],
         ['./img/img_0011.jpg', 'title11']
       ];

       $('#onebook3dSample').onebook(imgArray, {
         startPage: 1,
         flip: 'soft',
         skin: 'dark',
         bgDark: '#222222 url(./img/desktop.jpg)',
         pageColor: '#FFFFFF',
         slope: 0,
         border: 25,
         language: 'en',
         cesh: true
       });
     });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tanalab2様>まことにありがとうございます！無事にページがめくれました！！感謝の気持ちでいっぱいです！！！おかげ様でかなり前進できました。引き続きがんばります。